# Composición Vs. agregación

Tags: c#, uml

Estaba leyendo sobre UML y me crucé con este material, quería saber si mi interpretación en código de esa explicación es correcta.
Caso contrario, si la alguien me corrige y me aporta la version correcta lo agradecería mucho.

Referencias:

Agregacion => rombo blanco

Composicion => rombo negro

[image]

```
class mobile
    {
        bateria a = new bateria(); 
        simcard b = new simcard(); 
        memorycard c = new memorycard();
        msj d = new msj();
        soft e = new soft();
        camara f = new camara();


        public class msj { codigo }
        public class soft { codigo}
        public class camara {codigo }
    }
    class bateria
    { }
    class simcard
    { }
    class memorycard
    { }
```

Comment: De acuerdo a [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) no deben forzarse las etiquetas en el título.

Answer (score 7):

### Composición

Un objeto está **instanciando** *a otros objetos* **dentro** de su propio código.

En tu diagrama UML dices que *Mobile* está **compuesto** por *Message*, *Camera* y *Software*. (Nota aparte: Pongo Software sin **s** en vez de Softwares porque se recomienda que los nombres sean en singular).

Eso significa que en algún lado, **dentro** del cuerpo de la clase **Mobile**, o sea, dentro de su código, están escritas las líneas `new Message()`, `new Camera()` y `new Software()`. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Mobile
{
    Message message = new Message(); //Compuesto por Message
    Camera camera;
    Software software;

    public Mobile()
    {
        camera = new Camera(); //Compuesto por Camera
    }

    public void inicializarSoftware()
    {
        software = new Software(); //Compuesto por Software
    }

    class Software { }

}
```

Es *independiente* de si las otras clases están *anidadas* o no. Si dentro del código de un objeto creas una instancia de otro (usando *new*), entonces el primer objeto está *compuesto* por el segundo. 
[*Tomar esta definición con pinzas mientras no se lea lo siguiente*]

## Explicación en detalle de las notas de tu gráfico

Cuando quieras instanciar un objeto de la clase **Mobile** (`m = new Mobile();`), dentro de esa instancia de tipo *Mobile* (objeto) que se encuentra siendo referenciado por la variable *m*; se encuentran las referencias a las instancias de los objetos *Message*, *Camera* y *Software*. (En las variables privadas `message`, `camera` y `software`).
Por lo tanto, cuando pierdas la referencia a esa instancia de *Mobile*, **no deberías** poder acceder tampoco a las referencias de las instancias de *Message*, *Camera* y *Software* que se encontraban dentro.

Suponiendo que ahora *elimino la única referencia* que tengo *al objeto Mobile* (Una forma podría ser `m = null;`), lo que ocurriría normalmente, es que el *recolector de basura* (*Garbage Collector*), detectaría que ya no hay formas de acceder a esa instancia de Mobile, por lo tanto *destruiría la misma* eliminándola de memoria. A su vez, como *nadie más tiene referencias a las instancias de Message, Camera y Software* que se encontraban dentro, entonces *se destruyen también*.

Sin embargo; hay un detalle muy importante a tener en cuenta:

### ¿Qué pasa si mi objeto Mobile está entregando las referencias de Message, Camera o Software a otros?

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Mobile
{
    public Message message = new Message(); //Referencia pública
    Camera camera = new Camera();

    public getCamera()
    {
        return camera; //Entregando referencia
    }

    public Software crearSoftware()
    {
        return new Software();
    }

}
```

En este escenario, ¿*Mobile* está compuesto por *Message*, *Camera* y/o *Software*? Ahora se cuenta con la libertad de hacer algo como esto:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Mobile m = new Mobile();
    Message msg = m.message;
    Camera c = m.getCamera();
    m = null; // Prestar atención ahora.
    // Más código...
}
```

Ahora *cuando elimino la única referencia* a mi instancia de *Mobile*, *estoy destruyendo* a *ese objeto*. Sin embargo, si quiero ver *el contenido de las variables* `msg` y `c`, después de haber destruido a mi objeto *Mobile*, *se puede ver que siguen referenciando a los mismos objetos* Message y Camera al que mi objeto Mobile contenía.

En este caso; a pesar que dentro de la clase *Mobile* se están instanciando a otros objetos, en ningún caso existe composición.

Por lo tanto:

> **Composición**: Un objeto **A está compuesto por** un objeto **B**, siempre que se cumpla que **todas** las referencias a **las instancias
>   de B** *creadas por A*, **se destruyen** antes o **durante la
>   destrucción de A**.

---

### Agregación

Un objeto **tiene como atributos** *a otros objetos*, que fueron pasados como parámetros.

En tu diagrama UML dices que *Mobile* está **agregando** a *Battery*, *Simcard* y *Memorycard*.

Eso significa que **dentro** del cuerpo de la clase **Mobile** se definen atributos del tipo *Battery*, *Simcard* y *Memorycard*. Y que *Mobile* **NO** es quien *tiene la responsabilidad de instanciar* esos objetos.

Solamente *guarda las referencias a esos objetos* luego de haberlas recibido de alguna forma como parámetros. Por ejemplo:

```
public class Mobile
{
    Battery battery;
    Simcard simcard;
    Memorycard memorycard;

    public Mobile(Battery parametroBattery)
    {
        battery = parametroBattery; //Agregando a Battery
    }

    public void algunMetodo(Simcard parametroSimcard, Otro otroObjeto)
    {
        simcard = parametroSimcard; //Agregando a Simcard
        memorycard = otroObjeto.getMemoryCard();
        //Agregando MemoryCard solo si getMemoryCard() devuelve una.
    }

}
```

*Mobile* no está instanciando ningún objeto. Solo recibe instancias como parámetros. Esto lo harías por ejemplo:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Battery battery = new Battery();
    Mobile mobile = new Mobile(battery);

    Simcard simcard = new Simcard();
    Otro otroObjeto = new Otro();
    mobile.algunMetodo(simcard, otroObjeto);
    // Más código...
}

public class Otro
{
    public Memorycard getMemoryCard()
    {
        return new Memorycard();
    }
}
```

Ahora, si decides en algún momento escribir dentro del `Main()`, algo como `mobile = new Mobile(new Battery());`, la variable `mobile`, ahora estará referenciando a una **nueva** instancia de *Mobile*, mientras que la vieja instancia ya quedó destruida para siempre. Pobre de ella :'(. 
Sin embargo, al igual que antes, cuando exponías las referencias de tus objetos, si decides ver el contenido de `battery` por ejemplo, la misma vieja batería seguirá existiendo.

Está de más decir que en el caso opuesto, tengo la libertad de destruir la instancia de *Battery* y seguir manteniendo una referencia a un objeto vivo de *Mobile*. La destrucción de uno no significa la destrucción del otro.

Por lo tanto:

> **Agregación**: Un objeto **A está agregando a** un objeto **B**, siempre que se cumpla que **A** mantiene una **referencia** a **una
>   instancia de B que** *puede* **evitar ser destruida durante la
>   destrucción de A**.

**Nota**: *Sin embargo, este tipo de asociación, no suele tener una definición estricta. Por lo cual es normal que la interpretación de la misma difiera entre desarrolladores. Esta presentada acá, es la interpretación que pude tener sobre este concepto. Y mantiene la idea que se suele tener al respecto; si se destruye un objeto, no necesariamente se destruye el otro.*

---

### Asociación

¿Qué pasa en el caso del método `crearSoftware`? (*Usado en el contraejemplo de composición*). **Mobile** no se encuentra manteniendo ninguna referencia hacia los objetos **Software** que crea.

¿Qué pasa en el caso del método `algunMetodo` con respecto a la clase `Otro`? (*Usado en el ejemplo de agregación*). La clase **Otro** figura en el código de la clase **Mobile**, por lo tanto es claro que existe un tipo de relación entre ellos.

Existen asociaciones que no pueden ser clasificadas como asociaciones por composición o por agregación. Son solamente *simples asociaciones*. Y el único significado que expresan es que **existe alguna dependencia** (se conocen) **entre los objetos** involucrados.

Estas asociaciones pueden ser llamadas:

- **Fuertes**: Cuando un objeto **mantiene una referencia** sobre el otro. En otras palabras, *un objeto tiene como atributo al otro*.
- **Débiles**: Cuando un objeto simplemente conoce a otro sin mantener referencias con él.

Por lo tanto, se podría decir que las asociaciones entre objetos por composición y por agregación, son tipos de asociaciones fuertes. Mientras que en el caso de los métodos mencionados, *crearSoftware* y *algunMetodo*, son algunos ejemplos de asociaciones débiles.

Obviamente esto último depende de la interpretación que tengas con respecto a la asociación por agregación. Muchos difieren en la agregación que puede ser una asociación débil también.

---

### Resumiendo

- **Composición**: Una instancia *Mobile está compuesta por Message* si todas las referencias a las instancias de Message creadas dentro de Mobile son destruidas cuando se destruye la instancia de Mobile.
- **Agregación**: Una instancia de Mobile esta agregando a Battery si la instancia de Battery a la que está haciendo referencia la instancia de Mobile puede continuar existiendo cuando se destruye la instancia de Mobile.
- **Asociación**: Una instancia de `Mobile` está asociado a `Otro objeto`, si es que dentro del código de *Mobile* aparece escrito `Otro objeto`. (Por lo tanto, `Mobile` dependería de `Otro objeto`).

Answer (score 1):

La composición la utilzas cuando quieres que al destruir el objeto A se destruyan también B,C,D (en tu imágen `Mensajes`, `Cámara` y `Softwares`). La agregación es cuando quieres que los objetos tengan ciclos de vida separados. En código harías algo así (no se en que lenguaje posteaste asi que voy con pseudocodigo):

```
class mobile
    {
        msj d = new msj();
        soft e = new soft();
        camara f = new camara();
        bateria bat = null;
        simcard sim = null;
        memorycard mem = null;

       constructor (bateria b, simcard simc, memorycard memory){
         bat = b;
         sim = simc;
         mem = memory;
       }
    }

    public class msj { codigo }
    public class soft { codigo}
    public class camara {codigo }
    class bateria
    { }
    class simcard
    { }
    class memorycard
    { }
```

Así garantizas que cuando destruyas `mobile` se destruyen las compuestas pero no las agregadas.

Answer (score -1):

Mobile implementa bateria, simcard, memorycard (no podria heredar porque no hay herencia multiple en c#)

```
public class mobile : bateria, simcard, memorycard 
    {   
        public void msj { codigo }
        public void soft { codigo}
        public void camara {codigo }
    }
    interface bateria
    { }
    interface simcard
    { }
    interface memorycard
    { }
```

Comment: Esa respuesta no puede ser, por que en UML la agregacion se representa con un rombo y la herencia con una flecha, son dos cosas diferentes.